# Managing SQL query plain text strings in a .NET project

Tags: .net, dapper

I generally use Entity Framework for generating and interacting with my database.  I recently got a few requirements that will require optimizing performance.  As such, I was planning on using Dapper for this portion of the system.

One issue that I forsee is syncing changes to the database with the Dapper query strings.  I wont get the compile time checks that I get with EF so I'm wondering how people navigate these issues?  Is it just emphasis on tests or is there a way to work with Dapper such that database model checks can be performed at compile time?

Comment: As long as the method calling the DB uses the proper typings, you'll get the same compile-time check as with EF (or any other ORM for the matter). For the SQL itself, a simple test run will trivially uncover most problems, and those more complex you'll know you need a depper test suite. There is no fundamental difference here.

Comment: @Alejandro There is a bit of a difference. Assuming you've got EF migrations set up properly and aren't using EF to run your own SQL, then for the most part the code you write will line up with the database and at least be syntactically correct. That's not the case with Dapper (or raw ADO.NET for that matter) because there's no built in flow for keeping the application code in sync with the database code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not a built in way to check that the SQL you're writing matches the database schema, or that it's even syntactically correct SQL. If you want to catch that, then integration tests would probably be your best bet.